# How do i tell svnx to use a remote Working copy for the svn?

Tags: svn

Can I tell svnx that my working copy is on a remote server?

I have a remote repository that I checked out to a 2nd remote Linux box to work from. I now would like to setup svnx to look at the 2nd Linux box as the working copy.

I tried setting it up to use http:// instead of file:/// but it doesnt find it. I think I am missing something to expose that folder to the internet

I assume there may be a way to do it with ssh, but I cant figure it out.

Any way of doing that?

P.S. svnx is a cool subversion gui for Mac OS X

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt any application could do this over HTTP, given that HTTP does not allow e.g. directory listing. I would try mounting the remote working copy as a networked file system such as SSHFS.